# YUI: customizing message browser shows when cancelling window close event

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-browser, yui

I have a YUI application. 
Under certain circumstances I want to alert the user before he closes the window.
Therefore I capture the window close event and do

```
onWindowClose: function(e) {
        if (...)
        {
            YAHOO.util.Event.preventDefault(e);
        }
    }
```

The browser shows a standrd message: "Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page? Press OK to continue, cancel to stay in the current page".

How can I customize the message the browser shows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for onbeforeunload event and my answer in

[show a message box when user close IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564778/show-a-message-box-when-user-close-ie/564850#564850)

and

[ASP.NET: Warning on changed data closing windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250055/asp-net-warning-on-changed-data-closing-windows)

It may work for you.